# Access JS function inside return statement

Tags: javascript, requirejs

How do I access the functions `showDashboard` and `showTimeline` from the `$(...)` in the following code?

```
define(["jquery", "bootstrap", "./timeline"], function($, bootstrap, timeline) {

$(function(){

    $("#right-menu-dashboard").click(function(){
        // I would like to access the showDashboard function here...
        showDashboard();
    });

    $("#right-menu-timeline").click(function(){
        // ... and the showTimeline function here.
        showTimeline();
    });

    return {

        showDashboard: function() {
            // Some code here
        },

        showTimeline: function() {
            // And here too!
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to define the functions elsewhere first.

Comment: No, because that object you're returning is not accessible by any local symbol; it's just an object literal expression associated with the `return` statement. It's not got a name, in other words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways. I'd probably do it like this:

```
define(["jquery", "bootstrap", "./timeline"], function($, bootstrap, timeline) {

$(function(){

    $("#right-menu-dashboard").click(function(){
        // I would like to access the showDashboard function here...
        showDashboard();
    });

    $("#right-menu-timeline").click(function(){
        // ... and the showTimeline function here.
        showTimeline();
    });

    function showDashBoard() {
        // Some code here
    }

    function showTimeline() {
        // And here too!
    }

    return {
        showDashboard: showDashboard,
        showTimeline:  showTimeline
    };
});
```

But here's the *minimal* mod that will do it:

```
define(["jquery", "bootstrap", "./timeline"], function($, bootstrap, timeline) {

$(function(){
    var obj;

    $("#right-menu-dashboard").click(function(){
        // I would like to access the showDashboard function here...
        obj.showDashboard();
    });

    $("#right-menu-timeline").click(function(){
        // ... and the showTimeline function here.
        obj.showTimeline();
    });

    obj = {

        showDashboard: function() {
            // Some code here
        },

        showTimeline: function() {
            // And here too!
        }
    };
    return obj;
});
```

Or this may be a bit cleaner (just less minimal-mod):

```
define(["jquery", "bootstrap", "./timeline"], function($, bootstrap, timeline) {

$(function(){
    var obj = {

        showDashboard: function() {
            // Some code here
        },

        showTimeline: function() {
            // And here too!
        }
    };

    $("#right-menu-dashboard").click(function(){
        // I would like to access the showDashboard function here...
        obj.showDashboard();
    });

    $("#right-menu-timeline").click(function(){
        // ... and the showTimeline function here.
        obj.showTimeline();
    });

    return obj;
});
```

Note, though, that there's a difference between those. When you call `showDashboard` (for instance), in the first one, `this` will either be the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode) during the call. In the second two, it'll be the object you've returned from `$`. If you're not using `this` in those functions, it doesn't matter; if you are, it does.

Comment: I personally prefer the first solution. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @ShadowBroker: Glad that helped. In ES6, you'll be able to do this for the final return statement: `return { showDashboard, showTimeline };` (In ES6, the property names in the object initializer can be inferred based on the symbol we give for the value.) But not yet (unless you use an ES6 to ES5 pre-build step).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define the functions first, use them, then return them.

```
define(['foo'], function(foo) {
    function showDashboard() {...}

    $('#right-menu-dashboard').click(function() {
        showDashboard(); 
    });

    return {
        showDashboard: showDashboard
    };
});
```